# Choosing a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a website that will contain:

1) Sign in. The administrator must approve user's registration first.

2) A system where the administrator adds entries to a list and the users can make offers for each entry of this list.

3) If the administrator gives an entry of the list to a user, this entry will be added to a personal list of this user.

These are the basic things i want from the website. Which is the best way to make it? I think i am gonna make it with wordpress, but i don't know which theme to buy. Do you know any theme or plugin to help me with these 3 things?
Thank you in adnvance.

Comment: I think without coding php you will not be able to get what you want from wordpress. but there might be woocommerce plugins for "offers". check that

Comment: @niklas Thanks for replying. I agree, but i have not time for coding right now. I will check it.